# Scope variable problem undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part

I have a problem with my global variable. I saw that there is fundamental diffenrce the C language's Family.

I would like to reach and modify my variable "number" everywhere. I try with arguments or Returns but as I am not very experienced in JavaScript I failed.

Here is my code

```
var number;
    var message;

    $(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
    }); 

     function runCode() {
        // Specify a client context using the server-relative URL of the sub web, load the sub web, and call the ExecuteQueryAsync method.
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        targetWeb = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(targetWeb);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded1), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed1));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded1() {
        // On success, use get_ property assessor methods to return the value of the Title, ID, Language, uiVersion, Description, and Created properties of the SP.Web object.
        number = targetWeb.get_title();
        message = "<strong>Meldung: </strong>" + targetWeb.get_title();
    }

    function onQueryFailed1(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }



    function retrieveListItems() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Auftragsordner');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+number+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(this.collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
```

Comment: Is number undefined in retrieveListItems() method. If yes, call retrieveListItems() inside onQuerySucceeded1() method. and call only `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");` initially.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to this solution and it works perfectly !

Comment: adding it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number varibale is undefined in `retrieveListItems()` as `onQuerySucceeded1` method hasn't finished execution yet.

Call `retrieveListItems()` inside `onQuerySucceeded1()` method. And remove `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");` from

```
$(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
    });
```